# Is the server side logoutSuccessURL() call redundant in this tutorial?

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

In this [Spring Security Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) post successful logout the angular controller sets the location to `$location.path("/");`.

The Spring Security configuration also does it using:

`.and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();`

Is this redundant?  Should both the client and the server be doing this?